How to model change log history for opensearch document property, and aggregate on it?
I need to keep track of changes to a particular field in an opensearch document, and to be able to find aggregations on that field per date basis (for example, per day), or find count/IDs of docs that match a particular value on a particular date.
I thought of modelling it something along the lines of:
    "changelog": [
    {
        "from": "STATUS1",
        "to": "STATUS2",
        "from_timestamp": "2024-10-02T17:00:00",
        "to_timestamp": "2024-10-04T17:00:00"
    },
    {
        "from": "STATUS2",
        "to": "STATUS3",
        "from_timestamp": "2024-10-05T17:00:00"
        "to_timestamp": "2024-10-09T17:00:00"
    },
    {
        "from": "STATUS3",
        "to": "STATUS4",
        "from_timestamp": "2024-10-10T17:00:00"
    }]

Note the last entry might not have a "to_timestamp" which means it is valid until now. I might just put an infinite date instead. And of course there would be another field which will indicate the current status.
What I would like to achieve, is getting aggregation count of documents with a specific status, per day (using a range filter, for example, in the last day, 7, 30 days).
Also we would need to gather trends over time, for showing in a graph.
Example response for given dataset, assuming range filter is from 2024-10-01 to 2024-10-12
2024-10-01: "STATUS1": 1
2024-10-02: "STATUS2": 1
2024-10-03: "STATUS2": 1
2024-10-04: "STATUS2": 1
2024-10-05: "STATUS3": 1
2024-10-06: "STATUS3": 1
2024-10-07: "STATUS3": 1
2024-10-08: "STATUS3": 1
2024-10-09: "STATUS3": 1
2024-10-10: "STATUS4": 1
2024-10-11: "STATUS4": 1
2024-10-12: "STATUS4": 1

Of course 1 means how many documents match this status for the given date and is '1' for simplicity. And of course there would be more than one status for each date, it's just for simplicity
Essentially I would like to expand the from_timestamp and to_timestamp and aggregate inside per status type. I though a date histogram will work, but it doesnt work for my case since it doesnt work with a range. Also tried a date range field, didnt help either. I actually need to count the document for each date in between the range.
Does my modelling make sense? Is there a better approach?
